# How do I make the figure float [H] here when I use SCfigure?

Tags: graphics, floats

When I was using `\begin{figure}....\end{figure}`, I was able to fix the figure in the location using the `[H]`, `[h]`, or `[h!]` options, but that doesn't work when I use `SCfigure`. How do I fix a `SCfigure` in place?

```
\documentclass[12 pt , twoside, a4paper] {article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\begin{document}
\begin{SCfigure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{EffectiveArea}
\caption{height of cylinder=v$\Delta$t  \newline
volume of cylinder=$\pi (2r)^2(v\Delta t)$  \newline
number of collision per second=$\frac{N}{V_{molecule}}V_{cylinder}
\newline \quad \quad \quad \quad =\frac{N}{V_{molecule}}\pi (2r)^2(v\Delta t)$}
\end{SCfigure}
\end{document}
```

And the error is: `! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float`.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I have no idea where SCfigure is defined (you don't appear to give any clues) but if it has an optional argument the syntax will be `\begin{SCfigure}[h]` not `\begin[h]{SCfigure}` as `\begin` does not have an optional argument.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `SCfigure` is an environment defined by the `sidecap` package.

Comment: SCfigure from the sidecap package as @Jubobs said.
Yes my mistake, its should be \begin{SCfigure}[h], its still throwing the same error.
Tried the code block tip and didn't work.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You could use the figure environment instead, and the floatrow package to have beside captions.

Comment: @Jubobs Sorry Im new to the forum, still learning my ways. 
Thanks I got it working!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you still want to use the old package `sidecap`, remember that the floating specifier is the second optional parameter of `SCfigure`, so you have to use it as, for example,

```
\begin{SCfigure}[][h]
```

if you want the `h` specifier.

Also `sidecap` seems not to be compatible with `float`, so the `H` specifier cannot be used.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12 pt , twoside, a4paper] {article}
\usepackage[pdftex,demo]{graphicx}  %remove demo option in your document
\usepackage{sidecap}
\begin{document}
\begin{SCfigure}[][h]
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{EffectiveArea}
\caption{height of cylinder=v$\Delta$t  \newline
volume of cylinder=$\pi (2r)^2(v\Delta t)$  \newline
number of collision per second=$\frac{N}{V_{molecule}}V_{cylinder}
\newline \quad \quad \quad \quad =\frac{N}{V_{molecule}}\pi (2r)^2(v\Delta t)$}
\end{SCfigure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Otherwise you can switch to the `floatrow` package as mentioned in Bernard's comment and, issuing a command like

```
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=beside,capbesideposition={top,right}}
```

you can obtain the same (probably better) result using the `figure` environment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12 pt , twoside, a4paper] {article}
\usepackage[pdftex,demo]{graphicx}  %remove demo option in your document
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=beside,capbesideposition={top,right}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{EffectiveArea}
\caption{height of cylinder=v$\Delta$t  \newline
volume of cylinder=$\pi (2r)^2(v\Delta t)$  \newline
number of collision per second=$\frac{N}{V_{molecule}}V_{cylinder}
\newline \quad \quad \quad \quad =\frac{N}{V_{molecule}}\pi (2r)^2(v\Delta t)$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I have a question please, I'm  not understand well what is objective of the second parameter `\Begin{SCfigure}[**?????**][h]`, I was trying different values, but not see changes, I feel that is to indicate the width of the text? you can confirm me please. Thank you

Comment: @Robles, the first parameter is the caption width relative to the width of the figure.