# Can't move sidecap figures from top of page

Tags: floats, lyx, positioning, classicthesis, sidecap

Thanks for your help in advance. I am using LyX to typeset my dissertation. However when I export to plain LaTeX the problem persists, so I know is is a LaTeX problem.

I am using sidecap with ClassicThesis and I cannot (either using the LyX controls or by writing LaTex code) get figures to appear anywhere other than at the top of pages. Often it is convenient for me to have a small figure in the middle of the page. I have tried [h], [!h] and [H]. If I change the figure to a standard figure float then [h] produces exactly the result I would like.

Is there any way around this?

Yours in thanks,
Thomas

EDIT: Found the cause of the issue here: [How do I make the figure float [H] here when I use SCfigure?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153388/how-do-i-make-the-figure-float-h-here-when-i-use-scfigure)

In short, it turns out that the floating specifier is the second optional parameter of SCfigure, so to get the same behaviour as 
    \begin{figure}[h],
one should use 
    \begin{SCfigure}[][h]

This is maddening! Turns out that I have a LyX problem after all. Unless anyone can shed any light here, I will take it to the relevant forum.

EDIT 2: It appears to be a problem with the sdecap module (link in the comments). I have tried the method described in the LyX EmbeddedObjects manual but it returns "File ended while scanning use of \@argdef." when I compile.

Any other suggestions?

EDIT 3: An example of what I am trying to achieve: [image: A nice marginal caption]

Comment: You can try the `floatrow` package which has `captionposition=beside` key, and also a `capbesideposition={left/right/inside/outside,top/bottom/center}` key. It cooperates with `caption` and redefines and extends `float`.

Comment: Is there some module that you're using for `SCfigure`? If so, it sounds like a bug with the module, and you should contact the maintainer.

Comment: Yes, I will try to get some support from the module author. I am not going to bet a dissertation on that though... @TorbjørnT.

Comment: For now I will try floatrow which sounds better anyway. Thanks @Bernard

Comment: @Bernard it seems like floatrow is not compatible with the float package which (I think) is built into classicthesis... So no luck there. Any advice?

Comment: @Thomas James Mathew: Yes , `float` shouldn't be loaded with `floatrow, which extends it anyway. I looked at the classic thesis code: it doesn't load `float` so your problem doesn't come from here. But I've a `subfig` option, and this might be the source of a conflict. Do you loaad this option?

Comment: By the way, could you add a link to the module?

Comment: Hi @TorbjørnT. The module I am using is here http://theorie.physik.uni-konstanz.de/jrioux/lyx/ about halfway down the page.I have mailed the author but no response (yet). I thought about modifying the module source code so I opened it up and fiddled with it a bit but I was just hacking - I don't really know what I'm doing. Still no solution.

Comment: @Bernard Hmmm yes, if I load into a document without subfigs it compiles without errors - but I would need some help getting my layout right - I am trying to achieve tufte-style figures with the caption in the margin. Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: I don't know what are ‘tufte-style’ figures,, but `floatrow` has the same functionalities for grouped figures (and grouped figures) and it has a detailed documentation. Could post a minimal example as to what you want?

Comment: Hi @Bernard, I have edited the question to show a visual example of what I want. Creating a MWE is not always easy in LyX!